# Updating Label text on Bokeh plot

Tags: python, visualization, bokeh

I am trying to build a plot to display which job is more exposed to virus like [this][1] with Bokeh.
I tried to update the label when my selected value changes. However, It delay the changed. how example when I first select "nurse" in select, it did not show label, then when I select "doctor" , it showed "nurse" on the plot. please help me fix it. Thank you so much.

````
source = ColumnDataSource(full_table) 
p = figure(title="各職業之新型冠狀病毒之風險圖", x_axis_label='暴露疾病頻率', y_axis_label='與人接近距離')
p.circle('Expose_frequency',
           'Physical_proximity', name = 'allcircle',
            size=10,fill_alpha=0.2, source=source, fill_color='gray', hover_fill_color='firebrick', hover_line_color="firebrick", line_color=None)
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('職業','@TW_Occupation'),('Occupation','@Occupation'),('暴露於疾病指數','@Expose_frequency'),('與人接近距離指數','@Physical_proximity')])
p.add_tools(hover)

# Define a callback function 
def update_plot(attr, old, new):

       old_choice=full_table[full_table['TW_Occupation']==old]  
       p.circle(old_choice['Expose_frequency'],old_choice['Physical_proximity'],size=10,fill_alpha=1,fill_color='Gray', line_color=None )

       choice=full_table[full_table['TW_Occupation']==new]
       a=choice['Expose_frequency']
       b=choice['Physical_proximity']
       p.circle(a,b,size=10,fill_alpha=1,fill_color='blue' )

       citation=Label(x=choice.Expose_frequency.item()+0.5,y=choice.Physical_proximity.item()+0.5, 
            text=choice.TW_Occupation.item(), 
            border_line_color=None, border_line_alpha=1.0,
            background_fill_color=None, background_fill_alpha=0,
            text_font_size="8pt", text_align="center")

       p.add_layout(citation) 

# Add Select 
select = Select(title='Occupation', options=full_table['TW_Occupation'].tolist(), value='')

# Attach the update_plot callback to the 'value' property of select
select.on_change('value', update_plot)

#layout 
layout = row(p, select)

# Add the plot to the current document
curdoc().add_root(layout)```

Qeustion 2: 
I also want to wish to show an annotation text box aside the selected circle which looks like the hover tool just without hovering on it. 
[enter image description here][2]


  [1]: https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/03/15/business/economy/coronavirus-worker-risk.html?smid=fb-nytimes&smtyp=cur&fbclid=IwAR0UG6dj1eqMilukx9wit5FX4P4TxAodtvW8b0toGyYDCKygM087uZr8P38
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/El7Dv.png
````

Comment: It's hard to tell anything without the full code and data, but what you definitely _must not_ do in your case is calling `p.circle` and `p.add_layout` in the callback. Doing that, you're _adding_ stuff to the plot, not changing the existing stuff. Most likely, you will be fine with just using `CDSView` with filters.

Comment: As @eugene-pakhomov says, you do not want to create new items in your update function, rather update the data source for the circle. For the label, create citation outside the function and `set citation.text` in the update function.